# How to add variables to Drupal.settings using form#attached?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I found this example: http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/how-use-formattached-javascript-setting-drupal-7-form-api

I tried:

```
   $form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
            'data' => array(
                'my_module' => array(
                    'xx_code' => 'dsadsad',
                    'xx_key' => 'sadasd',
                ),
            ),
            'type' => 'setting',
        );
```

but with no luck, Drupal.settings.my_module is undefined

Answer (score 4):

Documentation is available:

[Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#attached)

```
$settings = array('id' => 'mymodule-element-1');

$form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
  'data' => array('mymodule' => $settings),
  'type' => 'setting',
);
```

[Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722)

```
$element['#attached']['js'][] = array(
  'type' => 'setting',
  'data' => array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')),
);
```

Both are roughly the same as what OP (@drupality) said worked for him in a comment on Jun 14 2013.

The code in the original question that the OP said he tried but fails seems roughly the same as the working code, so I can't see what the original error was.

Comment: Cheers @Adam, good that this is cleaned up